# How to synchronize greenlets from gevent in a WSGIServer / flask environment

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, gevent, greenlets

in my flask based http server designed to remotely manage some services on RPI I've approached a problem I cannot solve alone, thus a kind request to you to give me a hint.

Concept:
Via flask and gevent I can stop and run some (two) services running on RPI. I use gevent and server side event with respect javascript in order to listen to the html updates.

The html page shows the status (on/off/processing) of the services and provides buttons to switch them on/off. Additionally display some system parameters (CPU, RAM, HDD, NET).

As long as there is only one user/page opened everything works as desired. As soon as there are more users accessing the flask server there is a race between greenlets serving each user/page and not all pages are getting reloaded.

Problem:
How can I send a message to all running greenlets sse_worker() and process it on top of their regular job?

Below a high level code. The complete source can be found here: https://github.com/petervflocke/flasksse_rpi check the sse.py file

```
def sse_worker(): #neverending task
   while True:
       if there_is_a_change_in_process_status:
          reload_page=True
       else: 
          reload_page=False
       Do some other tasks:
          update some_single_parameters_to_be_passed_to_html_page
       yield 'data: ' + json.dumps(all_parameters)
       gevent.sleep(1)

@app.route('/stream/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stream():
    return Response(sse_worker(), mimetype="text/event-stream")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)
    http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

...on the html page the streamed json data are processed accordingly. If a status of a service has been changed based on the reload_page variable javascript reload the complete page - code extract below:

```
<script>
    function listen() {
        var source = new EventSource("/stream/");
        var target1 = document.getElementById("time");
        ....  
        source.onmessage = function(msg) {
          obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);
          target1.innerHTML = obj.time;
        ....
          if (obj.reload == "1") {
            location.reload();
          }
        }
    }
    listen();
</script>
```

My desired solution would be to extend the sse_worker() like this:

```
def sse_worker():
   while True:
       if there_is_a_change_in_process_status:
          reload_page=True
          # NEW: set up a semaphore/flag that there is a change on the page
          message_set(reload)
       elif message_get(block=false)==reload: # NEW: check the semaphore
          # issue: the message_get must retun "reload" for _all_ active sse_workers, that all of them can push the reload to "their" pages 
          reload_page=True
       else: 
          reload_page=False
       Do some other tasks:
          update some_single_parameters_to_be_passed_to_html_page
       yield 'data: ' + json.dumps(all_parameters)
       gevent.sleep(1)
```

I hope I could pass on my message. Any idea from your side how I can solve the synchronization? Please notice that we have here the producer and consumer in the same sse_worker function.

Any idea is very welcome!
best regards
Peter

Comment: How CPU intensive is the work that the `sse_worker` function does? I wonder if your greenlets are not getting enough CPU time. Also, it seems the data that is sent to all clients is not client specific, correct? If that is true, then it does not make sense to run a separate `sse_worker` task for each client. Instead, you should have a single background greenlet that generates the state information, and then each client should have a streamed response that sends the data then sleeps for some number of seconds, or until the data changes.

Comment: > How CPU intensive is the work that the sse_worker function does?

Comment: (...press enter to quickly) @Miguel, thanks for reading and your thoughts. _How CPU intensive is the work that the sse_worker function does?_ Not at all, just using psutil and time to extract basic info. But I like your idea of having one **single** background greenlet. You are right the state information is client independent. As soon a someone change the service status - this is valid for all others and should be presented to them accordingly. Question: how can i avoid creating new greenlets and serve all new incoming request via the single one - a code example would be great.

Comment: @Miguel, after a while i realized that I cannot reduce the sse_worker thread to single one - as the requests may come from different addresses. The workaround is to reduce the number of the connection to the server by adding to `WSGIServer(('', 5000), app).serve_forever()` `spawn=pool` and reduce pool to one beforehand. This is however the dirties work around, which does not actually solve my problem. I have to find a way to iterate through all spawned sse_workers.

Comment: Your sse_worker thread can be independent of any requests. you can start it when the server starts. This greenlet just gets the data and saves it to a set of variables that your request handlers can get (global variables, vars in a shared object, etc.). Then when a client connects, you create a greenlet for that client that just polls the data obtained by the sse_worker greenlet.

Comment: @Miguel - thx for your patience and answers. Now I understood your idea. This however requires that the complete page ("LED Indicators and service switch buttons) has to be rendered/updated via java script, I cannot use the flask render method. In this case reloading of the page is not needed anymore. Page will be always up to date based on a global/shared "state" variable. This is definitely an option. I'm testing now the "kill method from gevent.pool, which sends an exception to all running greenlets - in the exception handler I can push page reload. Anyway many thanks for your support.